# Charge Distribution - Trefoil

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coordinate-systems, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm trying to create a charge distribution in 3d in the shape of a trefoil knot. The trefoil has the following parametric equations.
$$x = \sin\theta + 2\sin2\theta
\\y = \cos\theta - 2\cos2\theta 
\\ z = -\sin3\theta $$

I want to create $\rho(r)$ in standard cartesian coordinates. Using standard Dirac delta functions I believe the following equation is generally correct.
$$\rho(r') = \delta(x' - (\sin\theta + 2\sin2\theta) )\delta(y'-(\cos\theta - 2\cos2\theta))\delta(z'-(-\sin3\theta))$$
However I'm getting a little tripped up with the constant value I should be placing in front of my three delta functions. I know I should have something like $Q/4\pi\epsilon_{0}$ but looking at other examples online has me a little bit confused. Since I'm in cartesian coordinates I don't have to include a Jacobian term from a coordinate change do I? As well any clarification about $Q$ and $q$ in terms of their meanings with regards to charge would be helpful. Right now I think one is the average charge and the lower case is a discrete charge, but I'm a little unclear as to when I use them. I think since I have a continuous distribution I use $Q$ but again I'm not sure. Any clarification would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues to unpack here.

First, note that what you have defined is not really the charge density. Let's write out this quantity explicitly:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\rho}(x',y',z', \theta) = \lambda \delta(x'-x(\theta)) \delta(y'-y(\theta)) \delta(z'-z(\theta)),
\end{equation}
Note that I have defined $\hat\rho$ with an explicit dependence on $\theta$. This isn't actually *really* the charge density, $\rho$. A fixed value of $\theta$ is a single mathematical point on the curve. If the total charge of the whole curve is finite, then the charge at any one infinitesimally small point is actually zero. The total charge density should really "sum" the charge densities from every point on the curve. I put "sum" in scare quotes because the curve is continuous, so we really should integrate. The *actual* charge density (**assuming** the charge is uniformly distributed with $\theta$ -- see the footnote below for more on this) is$^\star$
\begin{equation}
\rho(x', y', z') = \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d} \theta \hat{\rho}(x', y', z', \theta) = \lambda \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d} \theta \delta(x'-x(\theta)) \delta(y'-y(\theta)) \delta(z'-z(\theta))
\end{equation}

Now, let's apply a little dimensional analysis to our expression for the charge density. $\rho$ needs to have dimensions of *charge density* (charge per unit volume). Meanwhile, $\delta(\alpha)$ has the same dimensions as $1/\alpha$. Since $x$, $y$, and $z$ all have units of length, the product $\delta(x'-x(\theta)) \delta(y'-y(\theta)) \delta(z'-z(\theta))$ has units of $1/({\rm length})^3$, or $1/{\rm volume}$. Note I've implicitly defined the functions $x(\theta)$, $y(\theta)$, and $z(\theta)$ to be the formulas given in your question; e.g. $z(\theta)= -\sin 3\theta$. Finally, ${\rm d} \theta$ has the same dimensions as $\theta$. Therefore, for dimensional consistency,  $\lambda$ must have dimensions of *charge per unit $\theta$*. *In general*, you will need to worry about how you choose to parameterize your curve in order to fix $\lambda$. *In this case,* clearly $0\leq \theta < 2\pi$ is dimensionless. Therefore, $\lambda$ has units of charge.

Now we can think about how to fix $\lambda$. The total charge of a system, which I will denote as $Q_{\rm tot}$, is the volume integral of the charge density
\begin{equation}
Q_{\rm tot} \equiv \int {\rm d} x' {\rm d} y' {\rm d} z' \rho(x', y', z') 
\end{equation}
Incidentally, it does not matter what symbol we use to denote this quantity. We can use $Q_{\rm tot}$, $Q$, or $q$, or any other symbol, so long as we are clear on the meaning. There is no intrinsic difference between the notation $Q$ and $q$. I will stick with $Q_{\rm tot}$ in this answer, however, for clarity.

Putting this all together,
\begin{eqnarray}
Q_{\rm tot} &=& \lambda \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d} \theta \int {\rm d} x' {\rm d} y' {\rm d} z' \delta(x'-x(\theta)) \delta(y'-y(\theta)) \delta (z'-z(\theta)) \\
&=& \lambda \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d} \theta\\
&=& 2\pi \lambda
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\lambda = \frac{Q_{\rm tot}}{2\pi}
\end{equation}

---

$^\star$ This step hides a very important subtlety, since it's not completely obvious what measure factor to use in the integral over $\theta$. Ultimately this requires some physical input -- how is the charge distributed on the trefoil? I'm assuming here that the charge density is *uniform as a function of $\theta$*, based on the way you phrased the question. However, if the charge density is *uniform as a function of length*, then you need to include a Jacobian factor converting from arc length to $\theta$ in this step, and carry it through consistently. Depending on how you define things, the dimensions of $\lambda$ may be charge per length, rather than charge, in this case.

In a bit more detail, first define the arc length of the curve as a function of $\theta$
\begin{equation}
L(\theta) = \int_0^\theta {\rm d}\vartheta \sqrt{\dot{x}(\vartheta)^2 + \dot{y}(\vartheta)^2 + \dot{z}(\vartheta)^2}
\end{equation}
where $\dot{x}(\theta)\equiv {\rm d}x/{\rm d}\theta$. The total length of the curve is $L_t = L(2\pi)$.

Then instead of the expression for $\rho$ above, we want to use
\begin{equation}
\rho(x',y',z') = \lambda \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d} \theta \left|\frac{{\rm d}L}{{\rm d} \theta}\right| \hat{\rho}(x',y',z',\theta)
\end{equation}
Equivalently we could define $\hat{\rho}$ so it was a function of $L$ instead of $\theta$ (e.g. parameterize the curve by its arc length), and then define $\rho$ as an integral over $L$ (with no Jacobian factor) instead of an integral over $\theta$ (with a Jacobian factor)
\begin{equation}
\rho(x',y',z') = \lambda \int_0^{L_t} {\rm d} L \hat{\rho}(x',y',z',L)
\end{equation}
After this, one can follow the logic given in the body of the answer. I believe after turning the crank, the net result should be that $\lambda=Q_{\rm tot}/L_t$.

I believe (though I didn't check explicitly) if you pick, say, 100 uniformly spaced values of $\theta$ and plot the $x,y,z$ coordinates, you'll find that the points tend to "bunch up" near the "curvy parts" of the trefoil, and "spread out" on the "straight parts." On the other hand, if you pick 100 uniformly spaced values of $L(\theta)$ and plot the $x,y,z$ coordinates, the points will be uniformly distributed along the curve with no bunching or spreading out (by construction). Intuitively, the reason you need to worry about this Jacobian factor is to account for the difference in these discretizations.

Comment: thank you very much, just to clarify in the last series of equations. Since the integral for the dirac delta function integrates to 1, it disappears allowing us to find the value of lamba?

Comment: @Fuzzy_Bunnys Yes, for example $\int {\rm d} x \delta(x-x(\theta)) = 1$ for all $\theta$.

Comment: Make sure you understand the subtlety in the footnote though, you will get the wrong answer if you don't do this step correctly for the way you want to distribute charge on the trefoil.

Comment: I hadn't even considered the measure being an issue. I think based on your description I'll need to ensure its uniform as a function of length. My end goal is to get an analytic function for the electric potential for this charge distribution.

Comment: @Fuzzy_Bunnys OK, then I think you can essentially replace $\hat{\rho}$ in the answer with $\hat{\rho} |\partial L(\theta)/\partial \theta|$, where $L(\theta)=\sqrt{x'(\theta)^2 + y'(\theta)^2 + z'(\theta)^2}$ (where $x'(\theta) = dx/d\theta$, etc). One way to understand this is that if you discretize the integral over $\theta$ into point charges distributed uniformly in $\theta$, then you need the point charges to have different charges for the charge per unit length along the curve to be constant (unless magically $dL/d\theta= {\rm const}$ but I doubt it).

Comment: Equivalently you can parameterize the curve in terms of arc length $L$ instead of $\theta$ and replace $\hat{\rho}(x',y',z',\theta)$ with $\hat{\rho}(x',y',z',L)$ in the answer, and $\int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d}\theta$ with $\int_0^{L_t} d L$ (where $L_t$ is the length of the trefoil). Then I think $\lambda$ will end up being $Q/L_t$ instead of $Q/2 \pi$. The steps are conceptually the same, you just have the extra conversion factor to carry around.

Comment: I haven't checked this, but I suspect if you pick 100 uniformly spaced values of $\theta$ and plot the $x,y,z$ coordinates, you'll find that the points tend to "bunch up" near the "curvy parts" of the trefoil, and "spread out" on the "straight parts." On the other hand, if you pick 100 uniformly spaced values of $L(\theta)$ and plot the $x,y,z$ coordinates, the points will be uniformly distributed along the curve with no bunching or spreading out (by construction). Intuitively, the reason you need to worry about this Jacobian factor is to account for the difference in these discretizations.

Comment: @Fuzzy_Bunnys I'm sorry, I should have defined $L(\theta) = \int_0^\theta {\rm d} \vartheta \sqrt{x'(\vartheta)^2 + y'(\vartheta)^2 + z'(\vartheta)^2}$, in my comment above.

Comment: @Fuzzy_Bunnys I summarized these comments in an expansion of the footnote in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate the clarification. I'm glad to see I had the correct hunch based on your description of the measure issue. I'm trying to model a wire bent into a trefoil shape that is then charged to some voltage, so that presumes a uniform charge based on length. I'll have to work through all these notes in detail tomorrow morning!